# Why I can't make question on stack exchange app?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

Whenever I try to upload a question. It is showing that your limit is exhausted. Try after 7 days.

Can anyone suggest me how to come up with this problem? And ask my doubts frequently.

Answer (score 6):

It would appear that you have met your limit for question asking. [Making posts on the StackExchange network is rate-limited in a variety of ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/205676), especially for new and low-reputation posters.